# omit cell entries in xtable markdown

Tags: r, latex, markdown, knitr, xtable

I would like to report descriptive values in a table (I am sure they should be in a table and not in a figure). The data comes from a 3-factorial experiment, so the table that I am able to produce with xtable (I'm doing it in an Rmarkdown and Knitr and have never used LaTex) contains one line per data value along the format:

group    | condition  |  type | value

When all the lines are printed below each other, this in not very readable, for example the "group" entry remains the same for 10 lines. Is there a possibility to just print it the first time (in the first line) and then omit it until the "group" changes to the next group (only print it in line 11)? 
My table should have apa-format, so I use either rapa::apa(mytable) or papaja::apa_table(mytable) for the final print. 
Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I changed the data-frame that then is converted into a table.
 `ReplicationTable %>% mutate(dependent_variable = ifelse(duplicated(dependent_variable), "", dependent_variable)`
This replaces all entries with an empty string after the first unique entry in `dependent_variable`. This also works in grouped data-frames.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few different ways to do this.

```
library(data.table)

dt = data.table("Group" = c(rep("A",4),rep("B",4)), "value" = rep(1:4, each = 2))
knitr::kable(dt)

> dt
   Group value
1:     A     1
2:     A     1
3:     A     2
4:     A     2
5:     B     3
6:     B     3
7:     B     4
8:     B     4
```

We can remove duplicates across all rows

```
knitr::kable(dt[!duplicated(dt),])

|Group | value|
|:-----|-----:|
|A     |     1|
|A     |     2|
|B     |     3|
|B     |     4|
```

Or, we can remove duplicates according to specific rows

```
knitr::kable(unique(dt,by = c("Group")))
|Group | value|
|:-----|-----:|
|A     |     1|
|B     |     3|
```

Then, since that can match to multiple options we can specify which one we want to grab

```
knitr::kable(dt[unique(dt,by = c("Group")),.(Group, value), mult = "first"])
|Group | value|
|:-----|-----:|
|A     |     1|
|B     |     3|

knitr::kable(dt[unique(dt,by = c("Group")),.(Group, value), mult = "last"])
|Group | value|
|:-----|-----:|
|A     |     2|
|B     |     4|
```

**EDIT**

To not print values in a specific group that have been duplicated

```
dt$Group = ifelse(duplicated(dt$Group),"",dt$Group)
knitr::kable(dt)
|Group | value|
|:-----|-----:|
|A     |     1|
|      |     1|
|      |     2|
|      |     2|
|B     |     3|
|      |     3|
|      |     4|
|      |     4|
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! It's almost what I'm after. In your original dt table, what I would like is that the first row contains the "A" and then it's not printed, but the values are printed, so in the values column, it still says "1 1 2 2" just that the three last entries don't have an "A" in the Group column. Only in row 5, the "B" should be printed and in rows 6,7 and 8 again "B" should be omitted, but the " 3 3 4 4" should remain. So I don't want to lose any rows, just the entry in some cells in the Group-column. Thank you for your help though!

Comment: @lilla The new code will do what you're looking for

Comment: Sorry, I was busy with other things, but the edit is what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `duplicated` function with negation (`!`) to retain values of "group" only at transitions but be careful that is does
    not result in loss of information from other columns (if they are important). In the demo datset we retain only transitions of `cyl` variable.

```
mtcarsSubset  = mtcars[,1:5]

knitr::kable(mtcarsSubset)

#|                    |  mpg| cyl|  disp|  hp| drat|
#|:-------------------|----:|---:|-----:|---:|----:|
#|Mazda RX4           | 21.0|   6| 160.0| 110| 3.90|
#|Mazda RX4 Wag       | 21.0|   6| 160.0| 110| 3.90|
#|Datsun 710          | 22.8|   4| 108.0|  93| 3.85|
#|Hornet 4 Drive      | 21.4|   6| 258.0| 110| 3.08|
#|Hornet Sportabout   | 18.7|   8| 360.0| 175| 3.15|
#|Valiant             | 18.1|   6| 225.0| 105| 2.76|
#|Duster 360          | 14.3|   8| 360.0| 245| 3.21|
#|Merc 240D           | 24.4|   4| 146.7|  62| 3.69|
#|Merc 230            | 22.8|   4| 140.8|  95| 3.92|
#|Merc 280            | 19.2|   6| 167.6| 123| 3.92|
#|Merc 280C           | 17.8|   6| 167.6| 123| 3.92|
#|Merc 450SE          | 16.4|   8| 275.8| 180| 3.07|
#|Merc 450SL          | 17.3|   8| 275.8| 180| 3.07|
#|Merc 450SLC         | 15.2|   8| 275.8| 180| 3.07|
#|Cadillac Fleetwood  | 10.4|   8| 472.0| 205| 2.93|
#|Lincoln Continental | 10.4|   8| 460.0| 215| 3.00|
#|Chrysler Imperial   | 14.7|   8| 440.0| 230| 3.23|
#|Fiat 128            | 32.4|   4|  78.7|  66| 4.08|
#|Honda Civic         | 30.4|   4|  75.7|  52| 4.93|
#|Toyota Corolla      | 33.9|   4|  71.1|  65| 4.22|
#|Toyota Corona       | 21.5|   4| 120.1|  97| 3.70|
#|Dodge Challenger    | 15.5|   8| 318.0| 150| 2.76|
#|AMC Javelin         | 15.2|   8| 304.0| 150| 3.15|
#|Camaro Z28          | 13.3|   8| 350.0| 245| 3.73|
#|Pontiac Firebird    | 19.2|   8| 400.0| 175| 3.08|
#|Fiat X1-9           | 27.3|   4|  79.0|  66| 4.08|
#|Porsche 914-2       | 26.0|   4| 120.3|  91| 4.43|
#|Lotus Europa        | 30.4|   4|  95.1| 113| 3.77|
#|Ford Pantera L      | 15.8|   8| 351.0| 264| 4.22|
#|Ferrari Dino        | 19.7|   6| 145.0| 175| 3.62|
#|Maserati Bora       | 15.0|   8| 301.0| 335| 3.54|
#|Volvo 142E          | 21.4|   4| 121.0| 109| 4.11|


knitr::kable(mtcarsSubset[!duplicated(mtcarsSubset$cyl),])

#|                  |  mpg| cyl| disp|  hp| drat|
#|:-----------------|----:|---:|----:|---:|----:|
#|Mazda RX4         | 21.0|   6|  160| 110| 3.90|
#|Datsun 710        | 22.8|   4|  108|  93| 3.85|
#|Hornet Sportabout | 18.7|   8|  360| 175| 3.15|
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that's almost what I was looking for, I'm sorry, I wasn't able to better explain my problem: Instead of omitting all the lines in between, I would like to only omit the value of cyl if it's the same as in the line above. In the end, the cyl column shoud have only a number in it, if it refers to a new number of cylinders, the rest of the table should be printed as it is above, unaltered. I hope you understand what I mean? Or maybe imagine, I would sort the table by cyl so that the actual number of cyl is only printed when a new group of cylinders begins...